# how to store the session value in table in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i have an application in which books are sold. the customer add it to his cart and a session is created for that. now i want to add the items in cart to the order table so that admin can see what items are being ordered. can anyone tell how can it be done?

controller:

```
def checkout    
@cart = find_cart    
if @cart.items.empty?   
redirect_to_index("Your cart is empty")   
else  
@order = Order.new  
@order.items=@cart.items  
end  
end
```

using this code it stores hash value of items. i want to store the title of the book.

Comment: Can you please send more detail of the models and their assertions?